# Java Sorting columns in 2D Array of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have been working off of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907683/sort-a-two-dimensional-array-based-on-one-column). However, my data is arranged slightly differently.

Without going into **HOW** the data is retrieved, suffice it to say the resulting array looks like this

```
String[2][]
    [0] = String[4]
    [1] = String[4]
```

The actual data, then is as follows

```
data = String[2][]
  data[0]
    data[0][0] = "Columbia"
    data[0][1] = "Chile"
    data[0][2] = "Asia"
    data[0][3] = "US"
  data[1]
    data[1][0] = "B216"
    data[1][1] = "B217"
    data[1][2] = "A442"
    data[1][3] = "N665"
```

I want to sort the entire array by data[0] in alphabetical order. Yet I realized that the solution provided in the referenced SO question is working off of a different array format.

My expected result would look like

```
data = String[2][]
  data[0]
    data[0][0] = "Asia"
    data[0][1] = "Chile"
    data[0][2] = "Columbia"
    data[0][3] = "US"
  data[1]
    data[1][0] = "A442"
    data[1][1] = "B217"
    data[1][2] = "B216"
    data[1][3] = "N665"
```

I'm not entirely certain how to obtain these results without iterating over each element and shifting them to a new array.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just as an FYI, you are aware that "Asia" stands out a bit in that list?

Comment: @MadPhysicist That is some what intentional. Fake, example data and all

Comment: Sort `data[1][]` based on `data[0][]` (search SO, there are a lot of question about this step), then sort `data[0][]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting multiple arrays simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880500/sorting-multiple-arrays-simultaneously)

Comment: You may find this much easier by switching the dimensions of the array, so that each row describes one country. Then you're just left with sorting rows, as described in the question you linked.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Are you anti-Asia?

Comment: @nicomp Only against Asia being implied to be a country :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist no intention, here on insulting anyone :)

Comment: As in the answer to the question "Sorting multiple arrays simultaneously" that @Socowi cited, I would want to make an object then sort an array (or list) of those objects. `class Region { String regionName; String regionCode; //etc }`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Just teasing, I have healthy respect for angry physicists.

Comment: @StephenP. The more suitable approach may be to sort an array of indices with a custom comparator that references the first array by index since OP wants to minimize copying the data around. In your case though, just make the class implement Comparable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Solution

Taking the advice of Socowi and Stephen P and [Sorting multiple arrays simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880500/sorting-multiple-arrays-simultaneously) I came up with the following solution

As I am returning this data to a JSP to populate a drop down, I added a class for the model and iterated over the array adding a new instance of the model class to an Array List

```
for (int i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
  dataList.add(new LocationModel(data[0][i], data[1][i].trim()));
}
```

The model class implements Comparable and overrides the compareTo method

```
public class LocationModel implements Comparable<LocationModel> {
  ...
  @Override
    public int compareTo(LocationModel other) {
        return this.locName.compareToIgnoreCase(other.getLocName());
    }
}
```

Then I simply sort the Array List

```
Collections.sort(dataList);
```

This has solved my question.

Thanks everyone for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

Complete code [here](http://ideone.com/QDZ5pr)

1. Sort the internal `String[]` of `data`.
2. Add the `data` to an `ArrayList`

   ```
   List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
   // Sort the String array and insert it in List
   for (String dataArr[] : data) {
       String s[] = dataArr.clone(); // create new object of String array
       Arrays.sort(s); // Sort newly created String array
       list.add(s);
   }
   ```
3. Use custom comparator to sort this list. 
   3.1 Keep in mind that you need to scan through the entire `String[]` of the two arrays in comparision for finding the first difference.

   ```
   // Sort the list using custom comparator
   Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String[]>() {

       @Override
       public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {

           // optional: condition to check for string length equality
           if (o1.length == o2.length) {
               for (int i = 0; i < o1.length; i++) {
                   if (o1[i].equals(o2[i])) { // ** IMP **
                       // allows scanning through entire string array.
                       continue;
                   }
                   // Find the first different strings in both arrays
                   return o1[i].compareTo(o2[i]);
               }
           } else if (o1.length < o2.length) {
               // allow string arrays with lesser elements to appear first
               return -1;
           } else if (o1.length > o2.length) {
               return 1;
           }

           // When o1.length == o2.length and all strings are equal
           return 0; // no difference
       }

   });
   ```

Sample output for data (first line) and the sorted list
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can see three options for how to sort multiple arrays into the same order:

1. Create an array of indices, sort it using a `Comparator` that refers to the array you want to sort by based on the index, then rearrange the arrays according to the sorted indices. Here is a sample:

   ```
   Integer[] indices = new Integer[data[0].length];
   for(int i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++)
       indices[i] = i;
   Arrays.sort(indices, new Comparator<Integer>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
           return data[0][i1].compareTo(data[0][i2]);
       }
   });
   ```

   The index array has to be of type `Integer` rather than `int` because `Arrays` does not allow sorting primitives with a custom comparator. You can then rearrange both arrays by the index array doing something similar to the function below. I can't think of a way to do it in place without messing up the order and invalidating the index array.

   ```
   public String[] rearrange(Integer[] indices, String[] input) {
       String[] output = new String[];
       for(int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++)
           output[i] = input[indices[i]];
       return output;
   }
   ```

   This function does no error checking to see if the inputs are the same length and it doesn't use streams, which I am sure it can be rewritten to do. It is just an example of the concept. To use it:

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
       data[i] = rearrange(indices, data[i]);
   ```

   This is probably the least memory-intensive option for rearranging the arrays. It is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25880585/2988730) to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25880500/2988730) that I think is a duplicate of yours.
2. Create an object that holds all the elements at a given index and make it `Comparable`. This is the solution to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25880571/2988730) for the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25880500/2988730) referenced previously.

   ```
   public class Container implements Comparable<Container>
   {
       public final String country;
       public final String code;

       public Container(Sting country, String code)
       {
           this.country = country;
           this.code = code;
       }

       public int compareTo(Container other)
       {
           return this.country.compareTo(other.country);
       }
   }
   ```

   You would have to transform your data into an array of these containers and then sort it:

   ```
   objects = new Container[data[0].length];
   for(int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
       objects[i] = new Container(data[0][i], data[1][i]);
   Arrays.sort(objects);
   ```

   While this method does require copying the data over into a different format, it is actually more robust than working with an array of arrays because it groups the conceptually related items into a single item. This completely eliminates the need to check for things like array lengths being equal, as well as being generally much more object oriented. You could even rewrite your data input to just spit out an array or `List` of `Container` objects instead of a 2D array.
3. Create an explicit mapping between the countries and the codes, then dereference the values based on the sorted keys. This is sort of what #1 does, but it will allow you to at least sort one of the arrays in-place. If the mapping is an ordered mapping, you can just turn it into the sorted arrays directly.

   a. Unsorted mapping:

   ```
   HashMap<String, String> mapping = new HashMap<>();
   for(int i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++)
       mapping.put(data[0][i], data[1][i]);
   Arrays.sort(data[0]);

   String[] outputCodes = new String[data[1].length];
   for(int i = 0; i < outputCodes.length; i++)
       outputCodes[i] = mapping(data[0][i]);
   data[1] = outputCodes;
   ```

   b. Sorted mapping:

   ```
   TreeMap<String, String> mapping = new TreeMap<>();
   for(int i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++)
       mapping.put(data[0][i], data[1][i]);
   data[0] = new String[mapping.size()];
   data[1] = new String[mapping.size()];
   int index = 0;
   for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mapping.entrySet()) {
       data[0][index] = entry.getKey();
       data[1][index] = entry.getValue();
       index++;
   }
   ```

   These methods both have the disadvantage that they only really work well for two columns of data. If you have more than that, your values have to become custom objects or arrays of objects or something similar. Either way, this method is pretty clunky and I am only providing it to illustrate how you can jump through extra hoops if you really want to.

There are probably other ways, but as #3 demonstrates, I suspect that they will not be particularly efficient in terms of speed, memory or legibility/maintainability compared to the three shown here.

Also keep in mind that streams will let you do everything I have shown you here much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try that. Works perfect for me.

```
        Map<String, String> unsortMap = new HashMap<>();
                unsortMap.put("Columbia", "B216");
                unsortMap.put("Chile", "B217");
                unsortMap.put("Asia", "A442");
                unsortMap.put("US", "N665");

                System.out.println("Original...");
                System.out.println(unsortMap);

                Map<String, String> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();

                //sort by key, a,b,c..., and put it into the "result" map
                unsortMap.entrySet().stream()
                        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, String>comparingByKey())
                        .forEachOrdered(x -> result.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));

                System.out.println("Sorted...");
                System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: OP states: _"Without going into HOW the data is retreived, suffice it to say the resulting array looks like this"_ OP may be constrained to deal with this data structure and not be free to change it to a Map, so this doesn't answer the question of sorting a 2D array.

Comment: @StephenP You have a point. I am locked into receiving the data in the manner I described. But after that I am free to manipulate it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.mycompany.stringsortingby2darray;

public class StringSortingby2dArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String data[][]= {{"MADHYAPRADESH",String.valueOf(1)},{"BHARAT",String.valueOf(2)},{"usa",String.valueOf(13)},{"Australia",String.valueOf(17)},{"UTTARPRADESH",String.valueOf(5)}};

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            //for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(data[i][0]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).