# Using bubble method to sort an array in increasing order. Other arrays are then are at different indexes

Tags: java, arrays

This program is suppose to read a file that has the item, code, and price. I have it outputted to the screen to its represented index in the array. For example Item[0], Code[0] ,Price[0] all through each possible index. The program is suppose to sort through the Code values from smallest to biggest using the bubble sort method. I have gotten this correct so far. My problem is how do you get the all three to there respect variables. For example if wine ,1298, 8.99 are all in their respective index at [3] and then when the Code value is put into the bubble sort it is swapped to index [0]. How do you get the index of the price and Item to switch to index [0] also. That is my problem. We have just learned basic java so far in class so I don't know anything advanced yet.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Isiah\\Desktop\\xfiles.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        System.out.println("Item \t Code \t Price");

        String[] Item = new String[7];
        int[] Code = new int[7];
        double[] Price = new double[7];

        int c = 0;
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            Item[c] = input.next();
            Code[c] = input.nextInt();
            Price[c] = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(Item[c] + "\t" + Code[c] + "\t" + Price[c]);
            c++;

        }
        input.close();

        // Call Bubble Method

        bubbleSort(Code, Item, Price);

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Code \t Item \t Price");



        for (int i = 0; i < Item.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Code[i]);



        }
    }

    // Bubble Sort Method
    static void bubbleSort(int Code[], String[] Item, double Price[]) {
        int n = Code.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
                if (Code[j] > Code[j + 1]) {
                    // swap temp and score[i]
                    int temp = Code[j];
                    Code[j] = Code[j + 1];
                    Code[j + 1] = temp;

                }
    }
}




Item     Code    Price
beer    1357    12.99
apple   2357    0.5
bread   2123    1.25
wine    1298    8.99
pants   3009    6.99
sugar   2111    2.69
socks   3123    11.89

Code     Item    Price
1298
1357
2111
2123
2357
3009
3123
```

Comment: Encapsulating the values into a single object would be the prudent solution, if that's not possible then you probably need a "proxy" array which acts as a index lookup into the other arrays [**for example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880500/sorting-multiple-arrays-simultaneously/25880585#25880585)

Answer (score 2):

With your current code, you would have to swap the items in all arrays. So, when you swap `Code[i]` and `Code[j]`, also swap `Item[i]` and `Item[j]` and `Price[i]` and `Price[j]`.

A more object-oriented way would be to define a class with `Code`, `Item` and `Price` fields, say, `Thing`:

```
class Thing {
  int code;
  String item;
  double price;
}
```

and then sort an array of those: `Thing[]`.

Comment: @IsiahJones nothing stops you learning things outside the class.

Comment: Thanks for the advice got it up and running!